# How to retrieve a specific div data using jQuery Ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url:"A.asp?mmid=1&umid=2" ,success:function(result){
      $("#adfrnd").html(result);
    }});
  });
});
```

I am trying to retrieve test `div` from A.asp page
if I include

```
url:"A.asp?mmid=1&umid=2 #test"
```

it doeasn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does an error message appear? Try using firebug

Comment: no actually its load whole page...
but i need just a div contant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have the need to control the comunication you can keep simple like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#adfrnd").load("A.asp?mmid=1&umid=2");
  });
});
```

and remember to use something to debug the calls such as *the developers tools* provided by Chrome or *firebug* for *Firefox*.
If you have an error in your a.asp you won't see a thing. Checking the *network tabs* you see the output provided by yout a.asp call

Comment: i don't have error in A.asp coz i am just using a simple text in pure html

Comment: Thank bro its works...
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#adfrnd").load("a.asp?mmid=1&umid=2 #test");
  });
});

Answer (score 3):

You can use jQuery to wrap the resulting HTML andthen `find` or similar from within that.

```
success: function(resultHtml) {
  $(resultHtml).find('.whatever-class').html() // then use this for whatever
}
```

Comment: I didn't post a completed code segment as you didn't include enough details to specify what the "specific div data" was.

Comment: the "specific div data" is a text "success"
i want to load only word "success" but its load whole html codes...

Comment: that's because your'e replacing the element with "result". "result" contains the whole page. If you just want to print "success", then please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As for your comment in T.Stone's post, you just want to print the text "*success*". If that is so,, then why don't you just hard-code it like this?

```
success: function(resultHtml) {
  $("#adfrnd").html("success");
}
```

or did I misunderstood your comment?

Comment: actually if i success in load a specific div from A.asp page then i will dynamically change the A.asp #test div

Comment: change it to what? I'm sorry, I can't really understand what your'e trying to acheive here.

Answer (score 0):

#### Working Thanks to every one

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("button").click(function(){    

 $("#adfrnd").load("A.asp?mmid=1&umid=2 #test");    

 });

});
```

Its Works.... :)

Comment: Don't forget to mark the right reply that helped you to fix your issue as an answer (The true mark below the rating).